# How can I boot from Removable Disks?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

I'm trying to get my computer to recognize my micro SD adapter as a removable disk. I've inserted it into my laptop and changed the BIOS settings to boot from "Removal Disks" or CD-ROM (I'm using an external CD-ROM) but nothing happens.

The contents of the micro SD adapter is a Ubuntu installer.

How can I boot from the micro SD adapter (or flash drives) successfully?

Comment: Which procedure did you use to make the microSD card bootable?

Comment: IDK, is there a process to it?

Comment: Yup. You can't just copy files off a CD and boot it.

Comment: hmmm i used a universal USB installer, you can search for it on the web... i used universal USB installer so that i can use the .iso file(the ubuntu installer) on the micro SD adapter, then thats it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that YES it is *possible* but it depends on your motherboard and the *adapter* in use.

You will have more luck with a Compact-Flash or CFast since they use the IDE/SATA protocol directly. Actually you can buy a CF to IDE adapter which either lets you plug the CF inside the casing or with a reader-like slot fixed to an expansion slot. They are also apparently [available as CF-to-SATA](http://addonics.com/products/flash_memory_reader/adsacf.asp) as well, although I did not try these.